# Economics | A & B negotiating sale of asset. B owns asset but has no value, A know value, B knows probability. Find optimal offer.

Tags: probability, optimization, expected-value, maxima-minima, economics

### Problem Statement

Ann and Bob are negotiating the sale of an asset. Bob owns the asset currently but has no value for it. Ann has value somewhere in the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$. She knows her value, but Bob does not. He thinks that the probabilities are as follows:

| Value | Probability |
| --- | --- |
| $1$ | $0.4$ |
| $2$ | $0.15$ |
| $3$ | $0.25$ |
| $4$ | $0.2$ |

Assume that Bob can make only one take-it-or-leave-it offer *(i.e., if Ann rejects that offer, Bob cannot improve it, and if she accepts it, he cannot change his mind)*. Assume that if Ann is indifferent *(i.e., if her value is $4$ and the price is $4$)* she buys the object.

**a.** For each possible offer $1,2,3,4$, what is the probability that Ann accepts the offer?

**b.** What is Bob's expected profit as a function of the offer he makes?

**c.** What is the optimal offer?

### My Attempt

**a.**
$1 : 1 \\2 : 0.6 \\ 3 : 0.45  \\4 : 0.20 \\$

**b.**
$EP(p) = \bigg(1-\frac p4 \bigg)\cdot p$ with $EP$ being expected payoff and $p$ being the bid.

**c.**
Put the derivative of answer $b$ to zero to work out for $p$.
I get $p=2$.

Comment: Please edit to show your efforts.  And please delete the references to the points we'll get if we solve the problem, unless you actually intend on somehow awarding the points.

Comment: Post edit: Your answer for the first part are good.  I don't understand your answer for the second part.  The answer is meant to be a number.  Well, $4$ numbers...one for each possible offer.  What's $r$?  And your answer for the third part does not make sense.  There is no derivative to take here, there are only $4$ separate values.  I suppose you are just meant to pick the largest one of the four values, though this is not clear (we are not told $B's$ utility function so I'm guessing that he's just out to maximize his expected profit on this one transaction).

Comment: R was a typo and meant to be 4, I agree that that his presumptive aim is to maximise his profit

Comment: I still don't follow. You know the probability the offer will be accepted. That's what you just worked out in the first part. So, for each of the possible offers, just multiply the offer by that probability.

Comment: Yes, I did work out expected pay off as value * probability to get 1 for 1, 1.2 for 2, 1.35 for 3 and 0.8 for 4 giving 3 as the optimal bid however this answer was as rejected. Instead I was told to create a profit function f(x) with x as the offer Bob makes and to work out the optimal value by setting the functions derivative as = 0.

Comment: For $r \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, let $f(r)$ denote the probability that a bid of $r$ will be accepted.  Part (a) of the problem, which you have correctly answered, completely specifies $f(r)$.  Then, in part (b) of the problem,  for a specific offer $p$, where $p \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, your expected return is $$\text{EP}(p) = p \times f(p).$$  The above formula is based on *real-world* intuition.  Your expected return is the probability of receiving a payment *times* the size of the payment.

Comment: Not following.  Bob should never offer anything other than $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  Why?  Well, if Bob offered at $1.000001$ then Ann only accepts if her price is $2$ or higher, a $.6$ chance.  Thus Bob's expectation would be a hair greater than $.6$, and Bob can guarantee a payout at least as good (and often better) by offering at $2$.

Comment: Of course, you could take the payout as a function of $x$ as a continuous variable anyway, even if it doesn't make sense for Bob. But in that case, the expected payout isn't even continuous as a function of $x$, let alone differentiable (it is discontinuous at $\{1,2,3,4\}$, precisely the points you are interested in).